# One friend can join my Hamachi Minecraft server, but the other times out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hamachi

I have a Minecraft Bukkit server running on our Hamachi group IP. One of my friends can join, without timing out. However when my other friend joins everything stops moving, and he times out.

It has started happening since he upgraded from Windows 7 to 10. Occasionally he can stay on the server, depending on the map and time, however this is very rare. He can connect to other Minecraft servers and can also connect to our Hamachi servers on any other game.

Comment: Has your friend made sure the problem doesn't occur on his end? Does he have internet connection problems that disrupt his hamachi connection? Has he tried re-installing Hamachi?

Comment: Yes, he has reinstalled hamachi before but it didn't work. This problem only happens on our Minecraft server because he can connect to our gmod hamachi server and other mc servers just not mine.

Comment: Tell him to temporarily disable his firewall and/or antivirus and try to connect again.

Comment: Try using Ngrok or playit.gg rather then Hamachi, it interferes with the internet itself.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is pretty simple. If he is not whitelisted, whitelist him, and if that doesn't work, tell him to **run Minecraft as an administrator**. If the error persists, tell him to reinstall java, or download an earlier version of the Minecraft launcher.